# Parsing a timezoned Date string java

Tags: java, android

i m trying to parse a date in a json response in my android project .
the json is as follows :

```
{
    //some fields ..
    "date": "2019-12-29T17:01:58.000Z",
}
```

here is what i tried so far :

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 Date date = sdf.parse(jsonObject.getString("date"));
```

but i m getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-12-29T17:01:58.000Z" exception ..
Any help please

Comment: did you tried by using custom deserializer?

Comment: no , what is that ? @VikaS

Comment: see this https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-date-field-in-java-jackson-example.html

Comment: Avoid `SimpleDateFormat`, it's not thread safe. Use ThreeTenABP library instead - `LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding milliseconds to your format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`